# TemporaryFileWrapper instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python, with-statement, temporary-files, contextmanager

I'm generating the following NamedTemporaryFile -

```
## CONFIGURE DEPLOY.XPR
template = open(xprpath + xprtemplatefile, 'r')
joblist = open(joblistfilepath + joblistfilename, 'r')
temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
data = template.read()
listjobs = joblist.read()
template.close()
joblist.close()

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
values = {'<srcalias>':srcalias, '<dstalias>':dstalias}
data = replace_all(data, values)
temp.write(data)
temp.write("\n")
temp.write(listjobs)
temp.seek(0)
```

I then want to use it in another part of code here -

```
with temp() as f:
    count = 1
    for line in f:
        equal = '='
        if (str(count) + equal) in line:   
....
```

How do I re-use the temp file I've made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to call it:

```
with temp as f:
    count = 1
    for line in f:
```

or simply

```
with temp:
    count = 1
    for line in temp:
```

The object is *already* a context manager. You must have gotten this confused with `open()`, where it is the call to that function that produces a new file object that is then used as a context manager.

Take into account that at the end of the `with` statement the `temp` file object will be closed.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to leave it open?  I'm actually creating it, doing a with, using it for an external app and then doing another with.

Comment: Then *don't use it in a `with` statement*. Remove the `with` line, unindent the block.

Comment: That's all the `with` statement does. Call `temp.__enter__()` when it starts, and `temp.__exit__()` when done, optionally passing in an exception if there was one. The `temp.__exit__()` closes the file. The idea being that you'll close the file automatically whetever happens in the block, when the block is exited.

Comment: If you don't want it closed, then you simply don't use `with`.

Comment: Great thanks Martjin!  confirmed working.  have another issue but with 3rd party app so I'm going to figure that out first.